# Control the robot and show the Livestream in the same time

Tags: raspbian, python, raspicam

I want to show the Livestream behind the buttons without pressing "link to video feed"

This is the html code:

LIVE STREAMING - Surveillance Robot
    
        a {
            font-size: 30px;
        }

```
<div style="float:right">
    <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>
    <a href="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" target="_self">Link to Video Feed</a>
</div>

<div style="height:400px; width:300px; float:right;">
    <center>
        <h1><span style="color:#5C5C5C;">Circuit</span><span style="color:#139442"> Digest</span></h1>
        <h2>Surveillance Robot</h2><br><br>
        <a href="#" id="forward" style="font-size:30px;text-decoration:none;"> &#x1F881;&#x1F881;<br>Avancer</a><br><br></center>
        <a href="#" id="left" style="font-size:30px;text-decoration:none;"> &#x1F880;&#x1F880;Gauche</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#" id="right" style="font-size:30px; text-decoration:none;"> Droite &#x1F882;&#x1F882;</a><br><br>
        <center><a href="#" id="backward" style="font-size:30px;text-decoration:none;"> Reculer<br> &#x1F883;&#x1F883;</a></center><br>
        <center><a href="#" id="stop" style="font-size:30px;text-decoration:none;"> Stop &#x23F8;</a></center><br>
    </div>

<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.js') }}"></script>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        // Movement buttons: Send commands on mousedown, stop on mouseup
        $("#forward").on("mousedown", function() {
            $.get('/forward');
        }).on('mouseup', function() {
            $.get('/stop');
        });
        $("#backward").on("mousedown", function() {
            $.get('/backward');
        }).on('mouseup', function() {
            $.get('/stop');
        });
        $("#left").on("mousedown", function() {
            $.get('/left');
        }).on('mouseup', function() {
            $.get('/stop');
        });
        $("#right").on("mousedown", function() {
            $.get('/right');
        }).on('mouseup', function() {
            $.get('/stop');
        });

        // Stop button: Send stop command directly on click
        $("#stop").on("click", function() {
            $.get('/stop');
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the python code:

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request, jsonify, redirect, url_for
from aiortc import RTCPeerConnection, RTCSessionDescription
import cv2
import json
import uuid
import asyncio
import logging
import time

app = Flask(**name**, static_url_path='/static')

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

IN1 = 12
IN2 = 16
ENA = 18

IN3 = 22
IN4 = 13
ENB = 15

GPIO.setup(IN1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(IN2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ENA, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(IN3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(IN4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ENB, GPIO.OUT)

pcs = set()
def generate_frames():
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
start_time = time.time()
success, frame = camera.read()
if not success:
break
else:
ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
frame = buffer.tobytes()
# Concatenate frame and yield for streaming
yield (b'--frame\r\n'
b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
logging.debug(f"Frame generation time: {elapsed_time} seconds")
async def offer_async():
params = await request.json
offer = RTCSessionDescription(sdp=params["sdp"], type=params["type"])
# Create an RTCPeerConnection instance
pc = RTCPeerConnection()
# Generate a unique ID for the RTCPeerConnection
pc_id = "PeerConnection(%s)" % uuid.uuid4()
pc_id = pc_id[:8]
# Create a data channel named "chat"
# pc.createDataChannel("chat")
# Create and set the local description
await pc.createOffer(offer)
await pc.setLocalDescription(offer)
# Prepare the response data with local SDP and type
response_data = {"sdp": pc.localDescription.sdp, "type": pc.localDescription.type}
return jsonify(response_data)

## Wrapper function for running the asynchronous offer function

def offer():
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(offer_async(), loop)
return future.result()

## Route to handle the offer request

@app.route('/offer', methods=['POST'])
def offer_route():
return offer()

## Route to stream video frames

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
return Response(generate_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

def forward():
GPIO.output(ENA, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(IN1, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(IN2, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(ENB, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(IN3, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(IN4, GPIO.LOW)

def left():
GPIO.output(ENA, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(IN1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(IN2, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(ENB, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(IN3, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(IN4, GPIO.LOW)

def right():
GPIO.output(ENA, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(IN1, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(IN2, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(ENB, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(IN3, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(IN4, GPIO.HIGH)

def backward():
GPIO.output(ENA, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(IN1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(IN2, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(ENB, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(IN3, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(IN4, GPIO.HIGH)

def stop():
GPIO.output(ENA, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(IN1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(IN2, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(ENB, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(IN3, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(IN4, GPIO.LOW)

@app.route("/")
def index():
return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/forward")
def forward_action():
forward()
return ""

@app.route("/left")
def left_action():
left()
return ""

@app.route("/right")
def right_action():
right()
return ""

@app.route("/backward")
def backward_action():
backward()
return ""

@app.route("/stop")
def stop_action():
stop()
return ""
if **name** == "**main**":
app.run(host="192.168.1.199" , port=8081)
**

```
strong text
```

**

[![**the web interface***

### Heading

> `
> emphasized text

`

*][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdSzs.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdSzs.jpg)

Comment: your post is a mess near the end ... please fix it ... also, please format all of the code